# Devise nested form not creating profile

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms, user-profile

Rails 5.0.1
Devise 4.2.0

Hello, I'm building an app in which the user must fill a form to sign up, which includes the registration info for devise, and some personal info por their profile. I have made the models for user and profile, established their one to one relation, and added `accept_nested_attributes_for :profile` inside the user. I have also modified the registrations views to include `f.fields_for` for the profile, and until that point everything seems to work fine.

But, when I try to create a new user, and fill the required information, I get an error inside the view (from devise I guess) saying:

**1 error prohibited this user from being saved**

- Profile user must exist

I have already followed many guides on how to create a nested form with devise, and none of them seem to have this issue, and I have also searched a lot with no answer. Here are some snippets from my registration controller, user and profile model, and registrations/new view:

### **registrations_controller**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  def new
    build_resources({})
    resource.build_profile
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  protected

  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, 
                      keys: [:email, :password,
                      :password_confirmation,
                      profile_attributes: [:name, :art_name,
                      :birth_date, :location]])
  end
```

### **User model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  before_create :build_profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  # Devise configuration.....
end
```

### **Profile model**

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

### **Registrations/new view**

```
  <h2>Nueva Cuenta</h2>
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>

    <%= f.fields_for :profile do |b| %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= b.label :name, "Nombre" %><br />
        <%= b.text_field :name %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= b.label :art_name, "Nombre artistico" %><br />
        <%= b.text_field :art_name %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= b.label :birth_date, "Fecha de nacimiento" %><br />
        <%= b.date_field :birth_date %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= b.label :location, "Ubicacion" %><br />
        <%= b.text_field :location %>
      </div>

    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %>
      <% if @minimum_password_length %>
        <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
      <% end %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the sanitizers, I'm not completely sure how do I pass each attribute through, since most of the guides that explained this did with an older version of devise.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your profile model, try this:

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

it works for me